# ezurl operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url-routing, ezpublish

Is there a way to find out an eZPublish module-path in a plain JavaScript file?

I have to call a Module from JS, but i won't hardcode the url to the module. Is there a function like the ezurl() template operator in JavaScript or something to define the eZPublsih base path to concat with the module uri? I don't know how to find out the URL rewrite structure / siteacces...

I can't define the path by an 'in-template' js-snippet, because the script which needs the information is loaded before.

So i need something like this...

```
var moduleUrl = getEzPublishBasePath() + '/mymodule/myview';
```

or

```
var moduleUrl = createEzPublishModuleUrl('/mymodule/myview');
```

Thx. For your help.

Answer (score 4):

Can you declare a global js variable in your pagelayout, before you call your script that needs to use it?

```
var moduleUrl = {'/'|ezroot()};
```

Comment: As i wrote in my question... I can't, because in this case i have to wait for DOM-ready with all my js-works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concat the base URL of your website, then you should better use the ezurl() operator. When using ezroot() your siteaccess identifier won't prefix your URI, and that will lead into problems.

That said, people are usually lost and do not understand the real difference since ezroot() *works* for :

- a single siteaccess installation with RemoveSiteAccessIfDefaultAccess=enabled (this setting is not documented in the [configuration files section](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Configuration-files/site.ini)).
- multiple site accesses installation when using [host/port modes](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Concepts-and-basics/Configuration/Access-methods).

Remember that these operators have very different goals :

- [ezurl()](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Template-operators/URLs/ezurl) helps you process a system url (or an url alias which is a virtual URL of a system URL) like /user/login or {$node.url_alias}.
- [ezroot()](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Template-operators/URLs/ezroot) helps you process your resources URL/path for your stored-in-ezpublish files (such as pdf, flash, images, ...)
- [ezdesign()](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Template-operators/URLs/ezdesign) and [ezimage()](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Template-operators/URLs/ezimage) are used to help in processing static resources and are aware of the [design fallback system](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Concepts-and-basics/Designs/Design-combinations#automatic_fallback)